# Was ist das Gegenteil von „Spätwerk“?

Tags: single-word-request

Normalerweise wird der Begriff *Spätwerk* für ein Kunstwerk angewandet, das 
gegen Ende der Schaffensperiode eines Künstlers erschienen ist.

> *Die Zauberflöte* ist ein sehr wichtiges Spätwerk Mozarts.

Welchen Begriff soll ich nutzen, um ein Werk am Anfang der Schaffensperiode 
zu berscheiben, etwa

> Das Septett in Es-Dur (op. 20) Beethovens ist eins seiner bedeutensten *(???)-werke* für Kammermusik.

Comment: [Frühwerk.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaffensphase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mein erster Impuls als ich die Überschrift gelesen habe war "Frühwerk". Das funktioniert jedoch nur alleinstehend für die Gesamtheit der frühen Werke zusammen, und das gleiche gilt auch für "Spätwerk", zumindest meinem Sprachgefühl nach. Es gibt nur EIN "Spätwerk" und nicht 10.  Und bei Mozart finde ich "Spätwerk" eh ein wenig zweifelhaft, da ich es mit hohem Alter assoziiere.

Wie auch immer. Ich würde den Sachverhalt umschreiben...

> Das Septett in Es-Dur (op.20) Beethovens ist eines der bedeutendsten Werke aus seiner frühen Schaffensperiode.

Comment: Tja, vielleicht war es einfach Engleusch, was ich geschrieben habe. Denn auf Englisch heißt es "late works", d.h. es akzeptiert den Plural.

Comment: Beides wird benutzt. Man findet viele Fachveröffentlichungen mit Titeln der Art „xxx, ein Frühwerk yyys“.

Comment: Meine erste Assoziation ist auch, dass das Spätwerk das ganze späte Schaffen umfasst, aber ein einzelnes Werk aus dem Spätwerk ... ?

Comment: @userunknown, warum sollte man nicht sowohl das frühe Werk als auch ein frühes Werk als Frühwerk bezeichnen?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... "warum sollte man nicht einen Stuhl auch als Hocker bezeichnen? " ... man kann alles machen. Wenn man das Wort so benutzt wie du sagst, dann wird man es schon verstehen. Und wenn es oft genug passiert, dann hat es halt eine zweite Bedeutung. Für mich jedoch klingt es komisch. Ich will aber nicht abstreiten, dass es in der Fachsprache benutzt wird. Jedoch weiß ich nicht, was gegen "ein frühes Werk" spricht. "Frühwerk" muss ja nicht beides heißen.

Answer (score 4):

- Frühwerk
- Jugendwerk
- Werk aus der Blüte seiner Schaffensperiode
- ein Werk des/r jungen XY

Die Literatur kennt den Begriff "Erstlingsroman" - wenn aber bereits 37 Erzählungen und 67 Novellen erschienen sind schwerlich Teil des Frühwerks. Wie immer sind Metaphern möglich

- Jungfernflug
- Gesellenstück
- ...

Comment: kann die Blüte nicht auch spät sein? Wenn man jetzt 40 Jahre lang bratzenlangweilige Konzerte schreibt und dann mit 60 auf einmal kreativ abgeht, dann ist das doch die Blüte... aber nicht teil des Frühwerks. Gleiches gilt für "jung"... alle Werke von Mozart sind vom "jungen" Mozart

Comment: "In der Blüte schrieb er Schrott, jetzt zur Reife, wie ein Gott!" Sicher gibt es auch Herbstblüten, aber doch als Ausnahme. Wenn es aber kein Spätwerk gibt (Mozart, Hendrix, Joplin) dann braucht man auch kein Gegenteil davon abzugrenzen.